# Stop Safari 12.1 from auto-submitting forms

Tags: macos, safari, touch-id

Since the recent macOS 10.14.4 update which includes Safari 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4), last started to automatically submit web forms with login & password fields once a value for password or login is selected from auto-fill options.
This seems to be related to the new 10.14.4 feature where Touch ID got an option to confirm auto-fill in Safari. However I have it switched off but Safari still does this crap.
I'm curious if anyone else have the same problem and how to solve it.

**UPD** Starting Safari 13.0 (14608.1.49) auto-submitting is **disabled**!

Comment: I have this issue as well and I haven't figured out a way to disable the auto-submit of the forms. I like the security around touch-id but some AJAX and SPA apps don't behave well with this latest Safari update and can get into an infinite submit-reload due to touch-id.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have this issue too, and I've just spent a long time with an Apple Support chat agent.

This is a "feature" introduced in Safari 12.1.

[What's new in the updates for macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209149)

> Streamlines website login when filling credentials with Password AutoFill.

There is currently no way to turn this off. This is the solution the agent proposed. Submit a feedback to Apple:

https://www.apple.com/feedback/

> ...submit your feedback on the feature and your experience so far.

Maybe if we kick up enough of a fuss? It is a pain, and it also screws with captchas quite impressively...

Comment: i got the same problem. it gives problems when there is a captcha

Comment: It is also happening on `10.13.6`.

Comment: Correct webjay, this is for the Safari 12.1 update, not an OS update. I don’t know if Mac OS 10.12 will update Safari, to 12.1 but 10.13 and 10.14 both do.

Comment: I'm glad to say that this auto-submitting madness has stopped in Safari 13.0!

Answer (score 0):

I have seemingly found yet another sub-optimal workaround: disable Touch ID for autofill.

Confirmed to work on macOS Monterey and macOS Ventura.

1. Go to **System Preferences** (**System Settings** in macOS Ventura 13.0 or newer) > **Touch ID & Password**
2. Turn off **Use Touch ID for auto-filling passwords**
3. Enter the system password in the pop-up.

⚠️ Note: turning this off also disables Touch ID authentication for choosing and filling passwords in Safari, meaning that all remembered passwords in KeyChain can be selected and auto-filled without verifying your fingerprint.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me.

```js
<form id="myform" action="...">
    ..
    <a id="mysubmit">Submit form</a>
</form>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('mysubmit').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('myform').submit();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It was an unnecessary feature built into Safari in my opinion!

Comment: WHere do you add this and what does it do?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [StopTheMadness](https://apps.apple.com/app/stopthemadness/id1376402589) Safari extension to switch off auto submit behavior.

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stopthemadness/id1376402589?mt=12

Comment: Ha-ha! Really? Add $5 just to stop Sfari BS-ing users? No, thank you. I would rather stop using Safari where I can.

Answer (score -4):

I got the same issue with Safari 12.1, but I think it's not so bad
1. For sites which require captcha, the form is working like before, does not auto submit
2. For other sites, I got issue when can not click 'Remember me', but at the end I just click to that option first, and fill username & password.

So, I am totally fine with this feature.

Comment: This is not an answer. It may be a comment.